# What is the difference between function has() and function hasRole()?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

```
solidity ^0.4.24;
function has(Role storage role, address account) internal view returns (bool) {
    require(account != address(0));
    return role.bearer[account];
  }
```

vs

```
solidity ^0.8.0;
function hasRole(bytes32 role, address account) public view override returns (bool) {
        return _roles[role].members[account];
    }
```

Both return the same result, is it true?

Comment: Where have u found those functions?

Comment: for solidity ^0.4.24;
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.4.0/contracts/access/Roles.sol

for solidity ^0.8.0;
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol

Comment: Okay but why you are comparing them ? They improve always the structures and the Name of methods with each new version.

Comment: yes, I'm just trying to understand if they both do the same function.